# Setting up virtual bridge: Cannot find device "br0"

Tags: networking, bridge, dhclient

**Setting up a virtual bridge with Ubuntu with following config in** `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto brOffline 
iface brOffline inet static
 address 192.168.5.10
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 bridge_ports eth11
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 0.0
 pre-up ifdown eth11
 pre-up ifup eth11
 post-down ifdown eth11
```

*code: creating a bridge interface. Every bridge needs an adapter, here my physical network card eth11. To make sure it's working bringing the interface down and up again.*

**causes the restarting of the networking service ...**

```
service networking restart
service networking status
```

**... to display an error simmilar to**

```
 ifup[2304]: Cannot find device "brOnline"
 dhclient[2330]: Error getting hardware address for "brOffline": No such device
```

if your interface is called as the standard br0 it would sound like:

```
 default:
 Error getting hardware address for "br0": No such device
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Bridge util was not installed**

I moved from one system to an other. Target OS was a newly installed 17.10. the thing what was missing were the bridge utileties:

```
sudo apt-get install -y bridge-utils
```

The bridge simply could not be created because of missing tools...

Now `ifconfig` shows my shiny bridge

```
brOffline: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.5.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
    inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fe51:8eff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 68:05:ca:51:8e:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2  bytes 501 (501.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 107  bytes 10316 (10.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[Hint which helped me to find the solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1351120)

Answer (score -2):

first type command

```
ifconfig
```

then see all the headings of the output as
**wlp2s0, enp3s0, lo** etc.

try all the above-mentioned headings in place of "br0".

in my case when I replaced "br0" with "enp3s0" it worked fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure in total if you've understood the question and accordingly the answer. If you not have initialized a "br0" you'll have no luck.  I took in this question "br0" as an example name, cause this name is taken in most examples. What you do with ifconfig is listing all  interfaces known as status up ( saying online ) to the system. And what ever you've done this probably works best with a already existing adapter instead of a non existing adapter. The solution was that basically the fundament for providing a virtual bridge, was not installed. ;)

Comment: I don't have much knowledge regarding this particular problem, I told just what I did and that solved my problem, I thought this may help someone that's why I wrote, But for further info, thanks.